# math.h header file not working on AIX

Tags: c, aix

I have included `math.h` header file in my code and using `round` function but when I compile I was getting below error.

```
ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .round
ld: 0711-345 Use the -bloadmap or -bnoquiet option to obtain more information.
```

and I found IBM [link](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21499673) which explains why `math.h` not included then I have changed from `#include<math.h>` to `#include </usr/include/math.h>` but still I am getting the same error. Could someone please help me how can I resolve this?

`AIX` version is `6.1`

Comment: @Aravind: The header file that you #include just contains declarations, not definitions. To get the actual executable code (the definitions) you need to link with the correct library.

Comment: @OP: you should learn the difference between compilation-errors and linkage-errors.

Comment: Perhaps your math library lacks the function `round()`?

Answer (score 4):

It needed to provide `-lm` linkage option to link math library (`libm`) using gcc.
For AIX see for example ["gcc vs math library on AIX"](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.unix.aix/uWiTieGGnes):

> libm is contained in the fileset bos.adt.libm